# Active Directory don't create DNS records

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2019

In my Server with Windows Server 2019 Datacenter I have added Active Directory but I can't connect PCs in the local network to authenticate on the Server. When I try to add the PC to the Domain I get the error: Error 0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR) The query has been executed for the record SRV for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.MYDOMAIN.LOCAL

I checked in DNS and the record is missing. I also try to remove and add again Active Directory but it don't want to create the record.

How can I fix it? Or can I add the record manually? I try to do so and restart the service but the record is not populated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command:

```
nltest /dsregdns
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer: I try it and I get this message: "Marks: 0
Connection Status = 0 0x0 NERR_Success
Command execution successful" ...  But no records are added in the DNS